# Передать содержимое текстового поля редактора кода EditArea в переменную php

Tags: php, javascript

Хочу добавить в некоторую форму редактор кода EditArea

Подключаю и использую его таким вот образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="editarea/edit_area/edit_area_full.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  editAreaLoader.init({
    id : "text"   // textarea id
    ,syntax: "php"      // syntax to be uses for highgliting
    ,start_highlight: true // to display with highlight mode on start-up
    ,replace_tab_by_spaces: "2"
    ,allow_resize: "both"   
  });
```

```
<textarea id=text name=text cols="80" rows="15" style='width: 100%;'></textarea>
```

Проблема в том, что не могу вытащить текст из текстового поля для того, чтобы записать его в файл. Для этого, по всей видимости, нужно использовать определенную функцию. Я так понял, что вот эту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как именно - понять не могу. В js вообще не силен. Вдруг кто сталкивался именно с этим редактором кода, либо с какими-то другими. Либо просто знает js. *Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как передать текст из текстового поля EditArea в переменную php.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

именно этот редактор не знаю но предполагаю что он работает как и все остальные, а то есть тег `<textarea></textarea>` нужно поместить в тег `<form></form>` и отправлять его с помощью тега `<input type="submit">`. Выглядит это следующим образом:

```html
<form method="GET" action="test.php">
  <script src="editarea/edit_area/edit_area_full.js"></script>
  <script>
/* закоментировано что бы не вызвать ошибку, потому что нужно указать js файл с вашим редактором
    editAreaLoader.init({
      id: "text" // textarea id
        ,
      syntax: "php" // syntax to be uses for highgliting
        ,
      start_highlight: true // to display with highlight mode on start-up
        ,
      replace_tab_by_spaces: "2",
      allow_resize: "both"
    });
*/
</script>
  <textarea id="text" name="text" cols="80" rows="15" style="width: 100%;">
  </textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="отправить на обработку">
</form>
```

в данном примере данные из `textarea` попадут в файл test.php там их нужно и отлавлиать

Comment: Дело в том, что таким образом ничего не отправляется. Такой способ работает, если использовать обычную `textarea`. А чтобы передать текст из данного редактора кода нужно использовать функцию, которую я привел. Но как правильно ее использовать я не могу понять.

Comment: отправляется, вставьте код в html в свою страницу и нажмите кнопочку **отправить** , после этого в адресной строке смотрите что идет после test.php - это и есть данные из `textarea` , а в php страничке он будет храниться в глобальном GET массиве($_GET["text"]) .